# Django format email django errors

Tags: django

hi i would like  create a format for django email errors,  the email is automatic send by django in this case get the typical error format:
[image: typical error]

i would like get in the email report the **project name**, all type errors(404/500/etc)...
This is my settings:

```
ADMINS = (
  ('Diego Avila', 'diego.loachamin@test.com'),
)
#CONFIGURAR PARAMETROS EMAIL

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.test.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'diego.loachamin@test.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'dsdsad'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

please someone suggest or idea.. thanks..!!

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far. Remember that StackOverflow is not a "plz giv me codes" site.

Comment: not clear what type of format you want to do

Answer (score 2):

Django comes with such features built in. For 500 errors, it's a logging handler called [`AdminEmailHandler`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler). It will trigger when there's uncaught exceptions, and will include the traceback in the email body.

404 is different. That's not an uncaught exception, but you can intercept those with [`BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/middleware/common/#BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware) and send emails.

To customize how these emails look, you can create your own subclass of either or both of  `AdminEmailHandler` and `BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware`. Change the relevant logging and middleware config in settings.py to point to your custom logging handler/middleware.

For the logging handler, you can for example use the `format_subject` method to add something to the subject line of the outgoing email.

```
class CustomAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):

    def format_subject(self, subject):
        return '[ project name ]' + super().format_subject(subject)
```

Both the middleware and the logging handler uses [`django.core.email.mail-admins()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#mail-admins) to send the emails.